# Parse Facebook framework issue

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to integrate Parse Facebook framework. But I'm getting 9 errors constantly due to ParseFacebookUtils.framework (I'm writing in swift)

[image]

Once I remove that framework, the errors are gone.

These are all the required frameworks and I have included them all.

[image]

I want to use `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` but I don't get the autocomplete or anything.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please file a bug report to facebook. developers.facebook.com/bugs